# unable to set height of listView row height in row xml

Tags: android

here is my getView method of my custom adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            SingleEvent entry = listSingleEvent.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_event_row, null);
            }
            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(entry.getTitle());

            TextView byTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.byTextView);
            byTextView.setText(entry.getBy());

            TextView dateTextView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
            dateTextView.setText(entry.getDate());

            TextView descTextView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descTextView);
            descTextView.setText(entry.getDesc());


            return convertView;
        }
```

Here is the row xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/titleTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/byTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dateTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/descTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Changing the LinearLayout height to 300dp or something doesnt do anything. The row still just hugs the amount of content.

Is there a way to set the row height in the getView method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have to do is make the individual items in each row bigger if you want each row in the ListView to be bigger. I'm pretty sure the ListView controls how big each row is. This makes sense right? It's in charge of figuring out how to layout each row so it make sense it determines how big each one should be.

Answer (score 5):

You can increase the row height setting the `android:padding` attribute in your XML layout.
You can also set the `android:minHeight` attribute.